# How do I interrupt Java code that doesnt finish and doesnt throw ThreadInterruptionException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

A load of tasks are submitted to my application but it keeps hanging and I track it down to this code:

```
uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics.tokenisers.TokeniserWhitespace.tokenizeToArrayList(TokeniserWhitespace.java:133)
uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics.similaritymetrics.CosineSimilarity.getSimilarity(CosineSimilarity.java:142)
com.jthink.songkong.match.Scorer.compareValues(Scorer.java:74)
com.jthink.songkong.match.Scorer.calculateTitle(Scorer.java:704)
com.jthink.songkong.match.Scorer.matchRecordingOrTrackTitle(Scorer.java:652)
com.jthink.songkong.match.Scorer.calculateTrackScoreWithinRelease(Scorer.java:538)
com.jthink.songkong.match.Scorer.scoreMatrix(Scorer.java:396)
com.jthink.songkong.match.Scorer.calculateReleaseScore(Scorer.java:1234)
```

It is basically an string matching algorithm in a 3rd party library but it does not throw *ThreadInterruptedException* so does this mean I cannot interrupt it, but is certainly a long running process having run for 30 minutes. I have a reference to the thread monitoring this code but is there any way **to stop it**.

Of course I am looking to fix the 3rd party library but in the meantime I need a way to stop my application hanging by cancelling these hanging tasks. What makes it worse for me is that I use Hibernate, and a hibernate session is created in this stack and then because this TokeniserWhitespace method never finishes my session (and hence database connection) is never released therefore eventually I ran out of database connections and the application completely hangs.

Comment: What happens if you interrupt it?

Comment: Well I cant try it out because only happens for a customer but I assumed nothing would happen ?

Comment: There's at least a fighting chance you'll get some sort of exception back. Interrupts are widely mishandled, it's not uncommon for them just to be wrapped in a RuntimeException and rethrown.

Comment: Im still unclear whether interrupting a thread has any effect if the thread being interupted isn't actively check the isInterrupted() flag.

Comment: If it's just doing computation then no, it won't have any effect. But any attempt to use synchronisation or I/O will implicitly check.

Comment: Right so it will ave no effect in my case - so the only thing I can do (although its not recommended to) is use thread.stop();

Comment: An alternative is to run the problematic code in a separate process, and kill the process if it hangs

Comment: Zim-Zam why would that be better than just stopping the Thread ?

Comment: Thread.stop() has been deprecated because it's unsafe - it might corrupt the rest of your program.  Isolating the problematic code to its own process and killing that process will leave the rest of your program unharmed.

Comment: Another possibility is to use [Akka](http://akka.io/), which is a concurrency library that lets you kill and restart actors (which are lightweight objects that run on Akka's thread pool)

Comment: The canonical answer to this question is as follows: *With the cooperation of the code, you can interrupt it using any method it supports. Without the cooperation of the code, no method of interrupting it is assured of being safe. However, isolating the code to its own process generally makes it safe to terminate the process context so long as the code doesn't manipulate sensitive resources outside its process context.*" Such "sensitive resources" can include shared memory, server processes, physical objects, network connections, and so on.

Comment: In my case because Im just comparing two Strings I dont see how Thread.stop() could cause any damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try `Thread.interrupt()` as even though the interrupted exception isn't thrown it doesn't necessarily mean that the 3rd party library doesn't handle it correctly in some other way. If that doesn't work then I would consider `Thread.stop()` even though it is depricated in the hopes that the library's design can handle sudden termination and doesn't end up in an inconsistent state (due to the transactional nature in which you are using it, I doubt there are many shared objects to get corrupted). `Thread.stop()` will cause the event to stop immediately and throw a `ThreadDeath` exception no matter what it is doing and it was deprecated by Sun due to the chance of leaving shared objects in an unknown and inconsistent state.

Comment: So I tried Thread.interrupt() and it had no effect, but Thread.stop() worked perfectly with no problem. I think in the past Ive been nervous using this method but sometimes it is actually what you need.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Yeah, the reason it was deprecated was to prevent highly synchronized tasks from ending up in unknown and inconsistent states. Since this task isn't synchronized you should be okay. However, you should make sure that any cleanup or state modification is done in a finally block because failing to do so could result in something like not closing a file if Thread.stop was called while reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can can use the [Akka](http://akka.io/) library to wrap the problematic code - this will let you kill and restart the code if it hangs.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future;

public interface ProblemCode {
  public Future<String> stringMatch(String string);
}

public class ProblemCodeImpl implements ProblemCode {
  public Future<String> stringMatch(String string) {
    // implementation
  }
}
```

---

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.TypedActor;
import scala.concurrent.Await;
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;
import akka.actor.TypedProps;

public class Controller {

  private final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("Name");

  private ProblemCode problemCodeActor = getProblemCodeActor();

  private ProblemCode getProblemCodeActor() {
    return TypedActor.get(system).typedActorOf(new TypedProps<ProblemCodeImpl>(ProblemCode.class, ProblemCodeImpl.class));
  }

  public String controllerStringMatch(String string) {
    while(true) {
      try {
        // wait for a Future to return a String
        return Await.result(problemCodeActor.stringMatch(string), Duration.create(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
      } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // Await timed out, so stop the actor and create a new one
        TypedActor.get(system).stop(problemCodeActor);
        problemCodeActor = getProblemCodeActor();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In other words, the controller calls `stringMatch` on the problem code that has been wrapped in an actor; if this times out (5000 milliseconds in my example) you stop and restart the actor and loop through the controller method again.

`ProblemCode` will only execute one method at a time (it will enqueue subsequent invocations), so if you want to concurrently execute `stringMatch` you'll need to create multiple actors and create a router out of them / place them in a queue / etc.

Comment: It seems like you are claiming this library does the provably impossible. What happens if the problem code has broken a process-level invariant when you try to stop it? How can a library with no knowledge of the internals of the code it's stopping restore that invariant?

Comment: For example, say the library works like this: `1) If too many tasks are in progress, wait. 2) Increment the number of tasks in progress. 3) Do work. 4) Decrement the number of tasks in progress.` Interrupting the task during step three will cause the number of tasks in progress to increase without bound, eventually causing all tasks to wait forever. You *cannot* interrupt a task without the cooperation of the code implementing that task. What if the code has taken control of a physical object and is doing something analogous to driving or cooking?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In that case the intention is that killing and restarting the library would also restart the task count.  If the task count is a shared mutable variable then Akka is not an appropriate library to use (unless that shared mutable variable can be put in a parent actor that can also be restarted), and with the code snippet I've provided it wouldn't be possible for to create such a shared mutable variable - my intention was that if he was sufficiently interested in Akka then I could explain these details, rather than my giving a humongous intro to a fairly involved library.